# htaccess similar cases like Facebook or Twitter issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this piece of line in my htaccess that causes errors. I couldn't find a similar answer to my inadequate wording.

I am attempting to get "username/followers, username/following, etc" and also "settings/account, settings/password, etc". I stopped using sub folders for non-scripts and images, so everything is on the same level.

Now I know they have similar casing, but I am curious how Facebook, Twitter, etc manage to do this.

Do they condense to one large page to make it work? I know they prevent people from using settings and other root level names from being used, and I haven't quite gotten to that point myself.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1&selection=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/$ profile_settings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)$ profile_settings.php?selection=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_settings.php?selection=$1&upload=$2 [L]
```

If I remove

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1&selection=$2 [L]
```

Then everything works fine. How do I make this work with two pages?

I could do

```
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)/$ profile_settings.php?selection=$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't look as nice. If not right place to ask, please let me know.

Comment: @chris85 I tried that, it didn't do anything I could notice.

I probably should've shown how:

https://twitter.com/Twitter/following
https://twitter.com/settings/account

Work fine.

Comment: What is your document root folder? I know how to solve it but you will need to change to your document root folder

Comment: @OtávioBarreto I use public_html as the document root for all my php/html files.

Comment: @chris85 Right, all of settings are falling into profile_home when they should fall into profile_settings. And that code didn't prevent this. Apache version 2.4.23

Comment: @chris85 I mean something like this https://regex101.com/r/l6DNQn/3/ The user1 and user2 are public, but settings is to signed in person only. /settings redirects to /settings/account automatically now so I removed the ^settings/$ profile_settings.php [L]

Comment: @chris85 Sorry, yes, they match the first rule yeah.

Comment: Okay, so I add negative, but it causes my whole website to fall into settings instead though. Sigh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144279/discussion-between-chris85-and-user3113607).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second rule matches both directory structures. You can use a negative lookahead so requests starting with the `setting` are not matched by that rule.

```
^(?!settings)([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
```

You can read more about lookaheads here:

1. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html
2. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I'm having an issue, very specific. My htaccess now looks like this.

RewriteRule ^(?!404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1&selection=$2 [L]

The problem I'm having is /user will work, but in a rare case /someone does not work, and returns 404. And only stops doing that if I remove all the negatives.

Comment: Can you post a regex101 example demonstrating the issue? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I have a new post, I know the problem due to responses, but not a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089043/htaccess-negative-lookahead-issue/44089647?noredirect=1#comment75201395_44089647

The negative prevents any user with any of the matches from being the start of the username. Which is funny cause Twitter matches /settings, but /Settings can be a user.

Comment: Add `[NC]` after the rule to make it case insensitive. Sounds like you already got the answer on that other question though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
RewriteEngine On

# make sure to add your document root dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/htdocs/user/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.+)/?$ $2?id=$1&goto=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/htdocs/user/$2/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ $2/index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

so inside your server root dir `htdocs/user/` you must have a folder like /user/ and a file index.php  this htacess will replace the file `site/user/index.php` to `site/user/username` in the same user dir you need to have the `following.php` file so `site/user/username/following.php` in the same folder, I think you understand my answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a document root solution, not to use subfolders, I went away from that because it is not attractive and harder to manage. I may as well just not use folders and put user next to all of my profile_home rewrites, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It works in the root too , it will replace `site.com/index.php` to  `site.com/username` it's just replace in the code to your root dir and let this `.htaccess` file in the root of your server

Comment: It is too excessive to create folder for single file, since it is not attractive design or easily manageable. I was looking for non subfolder solution cause of this. I currently zip my public_html and upload import it into filemanager everytime I need to mass update and no subfolders makes it easier.

Comment: I think I did't explained you right you don't need to have a folder for single file `settings.php` also will be in the same folder of `index.php´ but the user will acess a url like `/username/` this folder don't even exists the htaccess rewrite it to the page `index.php` so in your php you have to get the url and save the username in a var to search user in database

Comment: You said I need a folder. You are not explaining clearly at all. I have public_html and all my files are in there. I use htaccess to change all files into links. This is just small portion that is conflicting. And I don't want subfolders to public_html for my files. So I have /user, /user/followers, /user/following, but also /settings/account, /settings/profile, etc. They conflict, but I see other websites make them not conflict.

Comment: Please give me temporary acess to your website, so I can configure it and explain it better how it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144282/discussion-between-otavio-barreto-and-user3113607).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I got the correct answer.