# Htaccess Negative Lookahead Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is a very specific issue to my hobby website.

I have this code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!assets|404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!assets|404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1&selection=$2 [L]
```

Now this for the most works perfectly, I can visit all of those links (url/404, url/i, etc fine and also visit (url/user1, url/user2)...

The problem comes from specifically going to one user so far that seems to be throwing a random 404. That user does exist and removing the lookahead fixes the problem and the user can be viewed, but of course those other links break.

I'm gonna provide some link examples directly for this issue:

/blog

/forum

/testingaccount

The above all work fine, but this very specific user does not work. And I can't even comprehend how it does this. The user exists, and the files etc all exist, but this one user is causing an issue.

/itsame or /forumerguy

Comment: `^(?!(?:assets|404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)(?:/|$))([^/]+)$ ...`

Comment: @Deadooshka Make an answer post so I can upvote and checkmark it. That worked the perfectly. https://regex101.com/r/l6DNQn/5

Answer (score 0):

In your case, no url that begins with your exclusions will work: /i... /blog...

You can do that:

```
RewriteRule ^(assets|404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)(/|$) - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1&selection=$2 [L]
```

Or if you need others rules after (assets|404|i|cha...), you can do that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(assets|404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(assets|404|i|chats|books|forum|blog|help|terms|policy|jobs|settings|reset|signup|signin|signout)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile_home.php?userdomain=$1&selection=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Actually, all of my exclusions work. It is just the one URL that is throwing the error.

Comment: Try with user `itest` or `itruc` or `forumer` with exclusion at left like **i**tsmeashleyc no link with i... works. etc.

Comment: You are right. Any user with starting with 404 or i or chats etc all do this.

Comment: You should not have changed the question because we will no longer understand what was not working

Comment: Your code is making things worse though, so we already knew what the problem was, but not the solution.

Comment: I am using it, but it is making none of the links from working. Where do I place in relation to my full htaccess?

Comment: Well then, it would appear you are not here to help, by removing my edit to suit your answer, but not solving my problem...

Comment: Try now with the code I just change. You can't change your question with my answer. Wait for another member's answer if mine is not correct for you